# Automating a boring task

Tags: powershell, loops, scripting, system-administration

The second half of my script does not function the way I want it to. I believe I am using the incorrect cmdlet. I am trying to add a group from active directory to the local administrator account on a laptop/pc. And after this add a domain user to the power user group.

I want to pull from AD the group name, which I thought this cmdlet would do so. Any ideas?

I only ran the second half but receive errors. I have tried other cmdlets but I think this one is the most accurate.

```
#change computer name of the device + condition 
$answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to change the computer name?'



# First condition - 1) name comupter 2) take user creds 3) Rename computer using stored cred 4) write host if yes is the answer
if ($answer -match "yes"){
    $computername = Read-Host -Prompt "What will be the name of the computer?"
    #This part of the script will contain your credentials to change the computername and priveledges
    $cred = Get-Credential -Message "This will be used to changed the computername. Do not worry!"
    #$cred = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your network username" - Uneeded string
    Rename-Computer -NewName "$computername" -LocalCredential $cred -DomainCredential $cred
    Write-Host "Computername has been changed to $computername successfully!" 
    }


 #Second condition - If answer is no move on to second portion of the script to set privledges
elseif($answer -match "no"){
    Write-Host "Moving to the next part of the script"
    }


#Third condition - If answer is anything else - loop to the beginning of the script to accept the right answer
else{
    write-host "Please answer with yes or no"
    }

#Second half of script        
#Adding AD group to local adminitrator 
$localuser= Read-Host "Enter username of the PowerUser."
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrator" -Member "memeber"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Power Users" -Member $localuser + "tamu.jaguar.edu"
```

Comment: Your `Add-LocalGroupMember` specifies the "Administrator" group which needs an "s" at the end: "Administrators"

Comment: Also, "Power Users" is not a local group, so you can't use `Add-LocalGroupMember` to add someone to that group. You need the ActiveDirectory Module which gives you access to the `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlet for that.